# Performance when adding a parameter to where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

I'm trying to understand this behaviour. My below statement takes nearly half an hour to complete.  However when I replace the parameter @IsGazEnabled (in the case statement of the where clause at the bottom) with a value of 1, then it takes just a second.

Looking at the estimated execution plan, when using the parameter and when it takes 30 minutes, most of the cost (92%) lies with a Nested Loop (Left Anti Semi Join).  there also seems to be some Parallelism going on.  I'm only just learning about Execution plans and I'm left a bit confused.  Very different to the plan produced when not using the parameter.

So how does having a parameter compared to not having one make such a difference to the execution plan and performance?

```
declare @IsGazEnabled tinyint;

set @IsGazEnabled = 1;

select 'CT Ref: ' + accountreference + ' - Not synced due to missing property ref ' + t.PropertyReference
        from CTaxAccountTemp t
        where not exists (
            select *
            from ccaddress a
            left join w2addresscrossref x on x.UPRN = a.UPRN
                and x.appcode in (
                    select w2source
                    from GazSourceConfig
                    where GazSource in (
                        select GazSource
                        from GazSourceConfig
                        where W2Source = 'CTAX'
                    )
                    union all select 'URB'
                )
            where t.PropertyReference = case @IsGazEnabled when 1 then x.PropertyReference else a.PropertyReference end
        );
```

Comment: What kind of join is used when you do not use parameter? You can try adding option(MERGE JOIN) or option(HASH JOIN) at the end of your query and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rethink this query. Try and avoid the `NOT EXISTS()` for starters - as thats generally quite inefficient (I usually prefer a `LEFT JOIN` in these instances - and a corresponding `WHERE x IS NULL` - the x being something in the right hand side)

The main cause of woe for you though is likely to be the CASE based WHERE - as that is now causing the inner query to be evaluated for EVERY ROW!. I think you'd be better left joining both sets of disqualifying criteria, but include the parameter in the join conditions - and then check that there is nothing on the right hand side of either of the 2 left joined criteria

Heres how I think it could be rewritten:

```
declare @IsGazEnabled tinyint;

set @IsGazEnabled = 1;

select 'CT Ref: ' + accountreference + ' - Not synced due to missing property ref ' + t.PropertyReference
    from CTaxAccountTemp t
    left join ccaddress a2 ON t.PropertyReference = a2.PropertyReference and @IsGazEnabled = 0
    left join 
        (
            ccaddress a
            join w2addresscrossref x on x.UPRN = a.UPRN
                and x.appcode in (       -- could make this a join for efficiency....
                    select w2source
                    from GazSourceConfig
                    where GazSource in (
                        select GazSource
                        from GazSourceConfig
                        where W2Source = 'CTAX'
                    )
                    union all select 'URB'
                )
        ) ON t.PropertyReference = x.PropertyReference AND  and @IsGazEnabled = 1
    WHERE 
          a2.PropertyReference IS NULL
          AND x.PropertyReference IS NULL      
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks James.  I've used the left join method before as well, however I'm just wary of creating duplicate rows due to bad data when using a join.  I also thought that having the case statement in the where clause would give it quite a hit, but it didn't seem to.  Only when I added the parameter.  Hence my curiosity as to why specifically the parameter would cause a performance impact.  But I will certainly take your suggestions on board.  Cheers.

Comment: @ScubaManDan - The `CASE 1 = 1` would probably get optimised away - hence why its only causing a hit when the parameter exists. The left join method is fine as a check for `NOT EXISTS` when there is duplicate data on the right side (think about it) - but not so as a substitute for `EXISTS`

Comment: Of course.  I didn't really even think about it when I used the not exists.  Cheers.

Comment: I've deconstructed what you provided James and putting the parameters in a join condition instead has worked a treat.  It goes much faster, so I'll mark this as the answer.  I'm still struggling to understand the root cause of why the original query took so long.  I'll just have to trust that it will come to me as I continue my studies.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can occur because SQL Server (the query optimizer) uses the value of the provided parameter when creating the initial execution plan.  If the values in some of your tables are not evenly distributed, the created plan may work really well for certain values of the parameter, but really poorly for others.  This is generally referred to a **parameter sniffing**.  You can get around this using query hints (OPTIMIZE FOR X) or recompiling the stored procedure before each run (WITH RECOMPILE).  You should read up on these options thoroughly before implementing as they both have side effects.

See a couple articles on Brent Ozar's site for more details, [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) and [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/).

Comment: I'd also suggest rewriting your query to use joins instead of nested(nested(nested subqueries))).  This might fix the issue all by itself.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I was just reading up on Parameter Sniffing.  I thought maybe it only applied to Procedures.  I'll have a look at those articles.

Comment: So far my reading on Parameter Sniffing all refers to it occurring in Stored Procedures.  This is a just a statement run directly in SSMS. :/

Comment: It can also occur in ad-hoc statements.  If you query sys.dm_exec_cached_plans you will see a field called objtype.  This tells whether the plan is a Proc or Adhoc.